# MPMediaLibrary.DidChangeNotification not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

This question is related to Xamarin.iOS.
I have been trying since many days to get MPMediaLibrary.Notifications.ObserveDidChange to work without success. I tried almost everything. Suspecting something bad with Objective-C binding, I tried direct objc calls too using Messaging API. Finally, I built a Native Library and made sure that it works by testing it with pure objective-c app. Native one with Objective-C works without problem. However, the same Library when used with Xamarin.iOS doesn't get MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification. I have created in-built selector etc within Native library so that I just call a 'C' function without argument and it works with objective-c app. However, when used with Xamarin, the same doesn't work. I have taken care of calling beginGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications().

Some people may suspect that My selector/delgate is not being called because of wrong use. However, every other notification is able to call my selector except this one. So syntax is not an issue, I suppose.

After all the efforts, I presume that there is something wrong in Xamarin settings, which is stopping me from getting MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification . I really dont know what exactly is it. So my question is - Can you guys get this notification ?

My test phone - iPhone6-8.0.2, Xamarin Studio Version 5.5.3 (build 6) Installation UUID: d84b8c6d-f992-4f19-8a35-c14bcd08420e Runtime: Mono 3.10.0 ((detached/e204655) GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme) Package version: 310000023 Apple Developer Tools Xcode 6.1 (6604) Build 6A1052d Xamarin.iOS Version: 8.4.0.16 (Indie Edition) Hash: 80e9ff7 Branch: Build date: 2014-10-22 15:09:12-0400

Thanks, Vinay

Answer (score 0):

For the Record, I am posting the answer.

Since 64 bit transition, The MediaLibrary change notification is stopped for 32 bit apps. If you build your app for 64 bit iOS, everything is fine. However, 64 bit devices with 32 bit applications won't receive these notification. I have tested it thoroughly on iPhone6. So I think this is iOS bug, which Apple needs to rectify. All the Music Player applications on App Store are unable to update library anymore since they are 32 bit.

For Xamarin Users, use Unified API for proper notification support.